# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on integer in C:\xampp\htdocs\pro\ProController\DatabaseConfig.class.php:47

Tags: php, mysqli

I am new to OOP  in PHP and MYSQL. I looked for the solutions everywhere but could not find exactly what I am looking for. I am facing with the

> Fatal Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() **on integer** .

As you can see it says an integer. Please let me know where am I making a mistake.

- Login Function in UserController is working well.
- I have created a separate function for fetch().

DatabaseConfig.class.php

```
  <?php

       /**  * Connects to Database  */ 
   class DatabaseConnect {  
   protected $db_host = 'localhost';
   protected $db_name = 'procusa';
   protected $db_user = 'root';
   protected $db_pass = '';
   private $conn;   


    public function __construct()   
     {      
        $this->conn = new mysqli($this- 
       >db_host,$this->db_user,$this->db_pass,$this->db_name);

        if($this->conn->connect_error) {
            header("Location: ../ErrorHandlers/DBError");       
          }          
           return true;     
        }

    public function query($query)
     {      
        $status = $this->conn->query($query);
        if(!$status) return $this->conn->error;
        else return 1;  
          }


    public function fetch($result) 

    { 
      $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
       if(!$fetch) echo "Could Not Fetch";
          else return $row;
    }

}


$con = new DatabaseConnect();

?>
```

UserController.class.php

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php

/**
 * Class Template For Users
 */

class ProcusaUsers extends DatabaseConnect
{


    function RegisterUser($password,$email,$phone,$username)
    {   
        $reg_query = "INSERT INTO `registeredusers` (`id`, `email`, `password`, 
         `username`, `regd_time`)
        VALUES (NULL, '".$email."', '".$password."', '".$username."', NOW());";

        if( $result = DatabaseConnect::query($reg_query) ) {
            $_SESSION['line'] = 1; //1 for ON Line
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            header("location: index.php");
        }
        else 
            echo $result;

    }

    function AddMore($name) {}

    function Login($email,$password) {

        $login = "SELECT * FROM `registeredusers` WHERE email='$email' AND password = '$password'";
        if($status = DatabaseConnect::query($login) ) {
            $_SESSION['line'] = 1; 
            $r = DatabaseConnect::fetch($status);
            return $r;

        } return false;
    }
}

$user = new ProcusaUsers();
?>
```

login.php

```
  <?php

if (isset($_POST['signin'])) {
    if($result = $user->Login($_POST['email'] , $_POST['password'])) {
         $row = $con->fetch_assoc($result);
           print_r($row);
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: **Do not store plaintext passwords.** Use `password_hash` and `password_verify` instead. Your code is open to sql injection attacks, you really should use prepared statements.

Comment: As @IncredibleHat mentions, **do not inject user data into SQL** without the appropriate security measures. This will allow your users to run arbitrary SQL against your database, often including write statements that will overwrite or delete your data, or read statements that will steal other people's information or credentials.

Comment: Additionally, you should understand the difference between `=`, `==` and `===`.

Comment: Yep, As I have solved the problem. I am re-coding everything to Prepared Statement. Thank you all for your valuable advises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DatabaseConnect::query` in your code returns `1`, but it should return a `mysqli_result` object.

At line `if(!$status) return $this->conn->error;` it must be identical comparsion with `false` value. Because, for example, if query `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...` will return `0`,  your code will return an error (see [converting to boolean](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting)), but actually it will be a numeric result. So change this line to:

```
if ($status === false) {
   return $this->conn->error;
}
```

You should to rename `fetch` method to `fetchOneRow`, because this name more accurately reflects what the method does.

Please follow naming conventions (for ex. [Zend naming convention](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.naming-conventions.html#coding-standard.naming-conventions.functions-and-methods)) and start your methods names with lowercase letter.

Comment: Yeah, that would cause the integer error. Sadly once he fixes that, he will run into more errors with that code shown. But I guess the question was about the integer error ;) So good job spotting that.

Comment: Thanks @camelsWriteInCamelCase